# WPF Touch Event Culling

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I'm a bit stuck with this one.

The UI for my app has a rectangle and opacity mask which alters to show different parts of the UI behind. What I want to do is let through any touch events that occur inside the transparent areas, and stop ones outside.

However, the only way I can get my rectangle to let through *any* events is to set IsHitTestVisible to False. I have tried capturing [Preview]TouchUp/Move/Down and set handled to False but this makes no difference.

Is there something I'm missing??

Cheers

UPDATE: Sorry if it wasn't clear, I don't expect the touch events to fall through on their own. I would check to see if they fell within in the mask and then set Handled to True. But it seems like even if I set Handled to False, the events still don't fall through. Nothing I seem to do allows the events to fall through, other than IsHitTestVisible=False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is normal behaviour, since opacity plays with... opacity, but still the rectangle is on top of other controls.
You can use clip instead of opacity (but you will have only a yes/no opacity, no shades)
Or
You could have a dictionnary (for instance) of all your controls that states wether it is visible or hidden by your opacity mask. Then you set your rectangle IsHitTestVisible to false, and in the Preview(TouchUp/Move/Down) event handler, you cancel the event or not depending if the control is visible or not.

Comment: I added a bit more info, see the update. Don't really want to have to manage a dictionary of objects beneath.

Comment: well it seems to me, still, that the behaviour you are encountering is normal : when the event reaches the rectangle, it should not go further since there is a non-null fill, even if the alpha channel (opacity) of this fill is sometimes 0. If your control are within regions of your user interface and inside different panels, it shouldn't be too hard to set/clear the visibility bit inside the dictionnary (for each control in panel  VisibilityDictionnary(control) = true ... )